# Cannot import module - why does sys.path not find PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, windows, python-import

I am running Python 3.6.1 on a Windows 7 machine. I have some scripts in `H:\Myname\Python\myscripts`.

I have created the user variable PYTHONPATH and set it to the folder above. I do not have admin rights so I can create a user variable only.

In that folder, I have a myscripts.py file with some functions.

If I try to access it running `import myscripts` from a file stored elsewhere, it doesn't work: I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`

If I print sys.path, the folder I have set in PYTHONPATH is not there.

Why? What am I doing wrong? Isn't sys.path supposed to show PYTHONPATH?
Does the fact that H is a network drive have anything to do with it?

I can't seem to find anything on the web for this problem in relation to Windows (but lots for Unix systems).

Comment: It works if I run sys.path.append('H:\Myname\Python\myscripts') - but I still do not understand why sys.path does not recognise PYTHONPATH

Comment: Check whether you misspelled *PYTHONPATH*, or have **-E** as an argument to *python*. Also I  don't know how you're launching *python*, but if you do it from a *cmd*, make sure to start a new instance **after** setting the var.

Comment: If you've set the `PYTHONPATH` value using the GUI environment variable editor or setx.exe, without also setting it in the current CMD shell via built-in `set`, then you'll need to start a new instance of CMD from Explorer. Generally only Explorer updates its environment in response to a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` "Environment" message. CMD doesn't even have a window to get this message (the console window doesn't belong to CMD or any other console application; it's attached to it).

Answer (score 1):

A common way to fix this quickly is to use
`sys.path.append("path/to/module")`
Be careful with `'\\'` if you are using Windows.

Not exactly answering your question but this could fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that there is a `._pth` file overriding the default behavior of `sys.path`. Remove or rename the `python._pth` (or `python36._pth`) file.

There was a `python37._pth` file included in my download of the [Windows embedded zip file](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) that caused `sys.path` to not include `PYTHONPATH`.

> To completely override sys.path, create a ._pth file with the same
>   name as the DLL (python37._pth) or the executable (python._pth) and
>   specify one line for each path to add to sys.path. The file based on
>   the DLL name overrides the one based on the executable, which allows
>   paths to be restricted for any program loading the runtime if desired.
>
> When the file exists, all registry and environment variables are
>   ignored, isolated mode is enabled, and site is not imported unless one
>   line in the file specifies import site.

[Using Python on Windows - Finding Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-modules)